# Google Analytics hits going to account, not property

Tags: google-analytics

I'm sending hits to my GA Property tracking ID, but it is always going to the first property (UA-nnnnnn-1) instead of the hit going to the tracking ID for the specific property I specified (UI-nnnnnnn-3).

Is it possible to send it to a specific property within an account?

Note: I'm testing out with Real Time.

Here is code:

```
console.log("Set up Google Analytics: AnalyticsId =", googleAnalyticsId)
ga('create', googleAnalyticsId, 'auto', {
            'storage': 'none',
            'clientId': sha
        });
...
ga('send', 'pageview', '/test');
```

The hit is going to a different ID (UA-nnnnnn-1) than specified and seen in my console.log statement (UA-nnnnnn-3).

Comment: This isn't related to programming and is therefore off topic. Can you please include your tracking snippet, or the code where you are defining the tracking object? GA would only track into the tracking ID that you define.

Comment: I updated with code snippet

Comment: Oh, I see problem now after doing your suggestion :) The ga was actually created earlier in initial snippet google provides. Can I change it's ID at a later time?

Comment: Yes, just change the ID where the tracker was first created.